# How to import data in EE?

Tags: channel, database

I have a CSV that I'd like to import into EE. Looking at `exp_channel_fields`, I think I am able to connect them to the appropriate columns in `exp_channel_data`. Basically, it seems like the value in `exp_channel_fields.field_id` is used to make `exp_channel_data.field_id_x` (where x is the `field_id` value).

But there is also this `field_ft_x` column. What is that for?

Is doing an import as simple as just putting my data in the appropriate columns in `exp_channel_data`? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally the best option is to use [DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab). It can import from CSV files, as well as XML and other formats.

The `field_ft_x` column stores the field "type". This is different from the fieldtypes you are probably thinking of though. For example, a "textarea" field has the option to choose which format it's in - things like None, Auto BR, HTML. You can also install new options in the list (and probably have already) such as Markdown.

Comment: The HTML's form field "type?" Why would that be in the `exp_channel_data`? Wouldn't that just be duplicating data?

Comment: Oh, I suppose the type could change? Thus, this is more of a historical record of the field type when the data was entered?

Answer (score 10):

To add an entry to EE, you need to enter data in a minimum of two places: an entry in `exp_channel_titles` and a matching one (by `entry_id`) in `exp_channel_data`.

The `entry_id` field is not auto-incremented, and so you're best to enter the data in a transaction, in case the (very rare) circumstance happens where the control panel is used to add an entry just as you're importing the data.  Or, you can write a big batch of queries and just start it at an `entry_id` you know isn't taken already.

There are, of course, circumstances where you have to add data more places: if it's a new author, if your data uses categories, if it uses matrix data (a common third-part add-on), if it has comments...

Each field stores its data in the `exp_channel_data` column called `field_id_##`, and the matching `field_ft_##` column is used to describe how that content should be OUTPUT later by EE. (i.e. `field_ft` is not a description of how the data is being stored, just of how it should be displayed. Data is usually stored as unformatted as possible.)

Each field has a default format, but every instance (entry) of data for any field can be set within EE to output its content in a variety of ways, so that's why that's there.

It's true, you don't need to use the third-party add-ons suggested here for simple data import needs. But the moment your data gets more complicated, they do a wonderful job of navigating that complexity and resolving data conflicts.  Datagrab tends to be updated more often.

- Solspace importer: http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/
- Datagrab: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 major add-ons for importing csv files (and other filetypes) into EE:

- Solspace importer: http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/
- Datagrab: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab

Both work similar, each has its own quirks and extras. A lot depends on properly formatted csv files, and both map to already defined channels/custom fields.

Comment: Are there non-commercial options? Can't I just do this via MySQL?

Comment: none that I'm aware of. But given the dev time they can save both are well worth the money, especially if you have to do repeated imports.

Comment: I would second DataGrab and underline the point about formatting the csv file. The import is easy, the hard bit it getting the file right to start with.

Answer (score 3):

+1 [DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab) nice & simple.

Answer (score 0):

I've used datagrab lot of time and it works well! It also imports in Playa fields. I only find some problems when I need to assign category/subcategories. I've never use solspace importer but it should be more  expensive than datagrab.